# Eclipse, formatting the code by hot key

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2010, ide

In Visual Studio I can say "Ctrl+E,D" and it will format the code. What about Eclipse, how do I format the code there this way? I'd like to do it by hot key.

Comment: CTRL+I indents your code. For formatting, see answer below.

Comment: Does not work. There is more, I'm not asking about indents only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not happy with the way eclipse formats the code, you can customise according to your needs,

Go to `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter`

Select a profile and `Edit` accordingly.

Comment: You understand me wrong. I'm happy, but sometimes if I write it slovenly, I want to format it by hot key. In VS there is no need to select it, I just can press Ctrl+E,D and it will be formatted.

Comment: @Alan even in eclipse, there is no need to select, just press Ctrl+shift+f it will format the whole class.

Comment: What about the whole file?

Comment: @AlanDert yes the whole file will be formatted, just press Ctrl+shift+f, if you place your cursor on the package and press it will format all the files under the package the same goes to the whole project.

Answer (score 2):

Select the code you want to format and use CTRL + SHIFT + F, this formats/indents the code.

Comment: What if I don't want to select it every time I want to format it? I want to format the whole file.

Comment: @ Marius Kavansky, to format the whole file, a simple Ctrl + A to select the whole file and then CTRL + SHIFT + F does the work.